# Error Message: "tex: fatal: Could not undump 1 4-byte item(s) from"

Tags: errors, texlive, format-files

if I try to run tex on Fedora Linux I always get an error message:

```
"tex: fatal: Could not undump 1 4-byte item(s) from /usr/share/texliv/texmf-var/web2c/tex/tex.fmt."
```

I removed and reinstalled texlive several times but that did not solve the problem.

I think this happened after I installed the german language packs with:

```
sudo yum install hyphen-de tex-hyphen-german
```

I tried it with different .tex files which have worked before.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Try `fmtutil-sys --all` (with `sudo` or whatever method is used in Fedora for acquiring superuser privileges).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message should mean that the `.fmt` file got corrupted in some way or the other.

A fix for this is to run

```
fmtutil-sys --all
```

or, if you don't want to recreate all formats,

```
fmtutil-sys --byfmt tex
```

(use the name at the end of the error message). It's important that you do this with superuser privileges, so prefixing the command lines with `sudo` or whatever method your operating system/distribution employs.