# xelatex: fatal: Could not undump 20182 4-byte item(s) from /var/lib/texmf/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt

Tags: xetex, fmtutil

I have the error

```
xelatex: fatal: Could not undump 20182 4-byte item(s) from /var/lib/texmf/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt.
```

no matter how I try to escape. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I tried:

- `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` (with and without `sudo rm /var/lib/texmf/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt`)
- `sudo apt install texlive-full --reinstall`
- `sudo apt install texlive-xetex --reinstall`

A few more details:

```
$ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 66.1; using 66.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.9
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.10.1; using 2.10.2
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.13; using 1.3.13
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 2.6.4; using 2.6.4
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
Compiled with poppler version 0.68.0
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.13.1; using 2.13.1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: seems like you have a corrupt fmt file also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141838/error-message-tex-fatal-could-not-undump-1-4-byte-items-from  try `kpsewhich -all -engine xetex xelatex.fmt` to see if you have any additional old xeletex.fmt hiding in your search path

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the output of `kpsewhich -all -engine xetex xelatex.fmt` is `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt`, and I tried both `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` and `sudo fmtutil-sys --byfmt tex` with no hope.

Comment: ah I hoped it showed two with an old one in a local tree. Sorry then I have no more guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New answer**: I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop (for various reasons, this is one of them), but if you ever come across an issue like this, try reinstalling the fonts from Microsoft.

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer --reinstall
```

There is something complicated going on with `.ini`, `.exe`, and other stuff related to `fontspec` which supports MS fonts such as Arials, Times New Roman, etc. I uninstalled and reinstalled `texlive-full` 10+ times, this issue indeed has almost nothing to do with `texlive`, but rather the font and format. Hope you don't end up reinstalling OS like me.

---

**Old answer**: So I downgraded the `xelatex` by downloading an old version from another computer, as well as replacing all `.fmt` in `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/xetex/` with another (probably) older version.

I then remove all the commands in the `.tex` file for font specifications, such as

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}
```

and every other thing that stands in the middle of the way. I'm sure this is not the only way, nor this is the best approach that can be taken, but at least it makes my `xelatex` compiler functional again.

Comment: Also tried `sudo fmtutil-sys --refresh`, as well as reinstalling the whole/partial `texlive` package. This affects both `xetex` and `luatex`.